# Failure to Boot Windows 7 after Ubuntu install

Tags: installation, grub2, partitioning, dual-boot, windows-7

My computer is a (brand new) PC notebook, without a CD drive running Windows 7. I followed this page to install from USB:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick

The installation went well and i am using Ubuntu now (v. 12.04 i believe)

I want to be able to dual boot Ubuntu and Win7
The problem is that the disc partitioning during the Linux install caused a problem with Windows, caused some problem with windows, and windows can no longer boot when i choose it at the GNU GRUB screen.

When i restart my computer i can successfully boot Linux, but not Windows 7. At the GRUB screen
- if i run Win7 normally, it freezes, shows a blue screen, and returns back to GRUB
- if i run Win7 recovery, i dont know how to access the files that i need in order to run windows again, so nothing helpful happens.

Can you please tell me what i would need to do(or link a guide) in order to run Windows again. (Windows and Linux is preferable, but if thats impossible going back to only Windows will help too)

Im guessing the easiest thing to do is just to reinstall both OS, or is there anyway to undo the partition i made during the install?

Thanks