# Systems Not Booting after Ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, boot-failure, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failure to Boot Windows 7 after Ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156944/failure-to-boot-windows-7-after-ubuntu-install)

I recently installed Ubuntu on my PC dual-booted with Windows 7. After rebooting it went through the usual startup screens, but the  OS selection screen never shows up. I cannot get either system to boot.

I have formatted the partition holding the Ubuntu to no avail and I really don't want to get rid of Windows.

I am currently stuck using the Live session disk to boot. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your grub entry, please try following process :

Try :

**sudo gedit /etc/default/grub**

and set

**GRUB_TIMEOUT=10**

ELSE

you can install **GRUB customizer** (http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/09/grub-customizer-3-0-released-install-it-in-ubuntu-12-04/)  to make your work easy. 
you will see following screen once you install GRUB customizer :

[image]

Let me know if this helps solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To get back into Windows, you’ll need to reinstall your Windows boot loader. I suggest this tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/